# How to use a known username and password to login in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm using netcat which takes in an IP and a port, and requires the user to input a username and a password to login. So netcat IP PORT will generate a welcome message and ask for the user's name and then password.
If I that the username and password are user1 and pass1, how do I feed them into netcat?

I have tried
(echo "user1" & echo "pass1") | ncat "$EXP_IP" "$EXP_PORT"
but it doesn't seem to recognize the password. It generates a message which asks for the password.
How should I do it in bash? I am very new to bash. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: What kind of protocol the server is expecting?

Comment: You can always use "Expect script" to pass password,.... which is straightforward. There maybe an easier way which I don't know (If you don't want to use expect)

Comment: I researched the "expect script" and found it useful. Executing ncat will expect a username and password. Could it do something like, while executing ncat, expect "username: " send "password"; expect "password:" send "password"?

Comment: Try this before anything more complicated: `(echo "user1"; echo "pass1") | ncat ...` You might need a ';` after `"pass1"`, but I don't think so. Recall that `&` is the 'run in the back ground command'. you just want the 2 `echo`s to execute one after another. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I have tried your suggestion. However it generates a message ask for the password. i.e. the pass1 was not successfully feed into ncat. I don't know if it's related, but the username provided ends up with a :)

Comment: did you try `(echo "user1"; echo "pass1" ; ) | ncat ...` ? (With a ';' after "pass1"?)  If that doesn't work, then I think you have to go the long route, with either `ssh` and it's keys, or with `expect` to monitor output from `netcat` and then send the password. Hm.. Last guess, try  `(echo "user1"; sleep 1; echo "pass1" ; ) | ncat ...` (added a `sleep`). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter sorry I missed your suggestion about adding ;  after pass1. (echo "user1"; echo "pass1" ; ) | ncat... worked!!!! Thank you for saving my life!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per our conversation in comments, it turns out you were very close, by changing the `&` character to ';' and adding  a second ';' character, your problem was solved. Change

```
(echo "user1" & echo "pass1") | ncat "$EXP_IP" "$EXP_PORT"
```

to

```
(echo "user1" ; echo "pass1" ; ) | ncat "$EXP_IP" "$EXP_PORT"
# ------------^here----------^and here
```

The semicolons terminate each command, so the "next" command can be executed. For the case for `echo "pass1" ;`, this is the final command in the sub-shell grouping, so having the `;` char allows `echo` to complete, and the subshell to complete and close. I'm not going to venture to guess exactly when the values are being sent to `ncat`.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the web site.

You need to send your username and password back using an HTTP POST or HTTP PUT request, which I would use [curl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) to do. You also need to look at the traffic when you look at the page in a normal web site. See what is sent back to the server and how the POST request is formatted, the variable names for what is sent back will, again, depend on the web site. When you log in normally via browser you can use the web console in your browser to figure out what was sent back, and replicate that POST request.

Comment: I think I did not describe my question clearly. Basically, the netcat will just ask for a username and password that I already know. I just want to know how to format the username&password inputs so that when netcat ask for the name and password, I can give the both information to it.

Comment: If you are trying to simulate real interactivity ("...when netcat asks for the name and password") you are working on a very difficult problem and will be better off following @Aman's suggestion to use Expect. If you want to *assume* some time delays that will probably work some of the time, you can do it in bash with subshells, echo, and sleep. I recommend you investigate Expect.

Comment: ccczhang -- I know that is what you're saying. What I am saying is that the input format varies *heavily* with what website you're targeting, since the form field names and input method for said username and password varies with how the web designer programmed the web site. Actually, this is a huge reason why I must agree with mpez0 and @Aman. Expect was built for stuff like this.